# NodeJS readdirSync ignore common patterns (i.e. '.svn', '.git', '.DS_Store', 'thumbs.db')

Tags: node.js

Is there any way for readdir or readdirSync to ignore common patterns (i.e. '.svn', '.git', '.DS_Store', 'thumbs.db')?  Apparently not from docs, but is there a good wrapper fs library to use that can do this?

Docs: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/fs.html#fs.readdirSync

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually no:

From nodejs sources:deps\uv\src\win\fs.c line 747:

```
  747:  if (name[0] != L'.' || (name[1] && (name[1] != L'.' || name[2]))) {
```

This excludes just the . and .. paths as the documentation says.